# 4 Div Blocks in a row with 2 divs in each block

Tags: css, html

Is this code using the best practices for what I'm trying to do? Basically I want four div blocks to fill the space at 100% (each div block would be 25%).

Then in each div block, I would like to have an image on the left and text on the right (with a 20 px space in between the image and text)

How do I figure out the percentage of the text? Since I have the image percentage at 33% with the 20 px margin-right.

http://jsfiddle.net/UMf3k/137/

```
    <div id="wrapper-resources">
    <div id="resources_row">
        <div class="resources_cell1">
            <div class="resources_lt">
            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/aha-soft/food/256/apple-icon.png" width="76" height="76" /> 
            </div>
            <div class="resources_rt">
                <p><strong>Webinar</strong>
                Capital Projects: Hidden Gems In The World</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="resources_cell2">
            <div class="resources_lt">
            <img src="http://www.purelynaturalskin.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Sweet-Orange-Oil.jpg" width="76" height="76" /> 
            </div>
            <div class="resources_rt">
                <p><strong>Article</strong>
                 Capital Projects: Hidden Gems In The World</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="resources_cell3">
            <div class="resources_lt">
            <img src="http://images.wikia.com/uncyclopedia/images/archive/d/d4/20080204233721!Pear.jpg" width="76" height="76" /> 
            </div>
            <div class="resources_rt">
                <p><strong>Blog</strong>
                 Capital Projects: Hidden Gems In The World</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="resources_cell4">
            <div class="resources_lt">
            <img src="http://www.whataboutwatermelon.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/watermelon_simple.jpg" width="76" height="76" /> 
            </div>
            <div class="resources_rt">
                <p><strong>News</strong><br>
                 Capital Projects: Hidden Gems In The World</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

#wrapper-resources {
position:relative;
width:100%;
border: none;
margin: 50px 0 0 0;
```

}

```
#resources_row {
height:100%;
white-space:nowrap;
}

.resources_cell1, .resources_cell2, .resources_cell3, .resources_cell4 {
height:100%;
width:25%;
display:inline-block;
white-space:normal;
border: 1px solid red;    
}

.resources_lt {
height:100%;
width:33%;
display:inline-block;
white-space:normal;
margin-right: 20px;
vertical-align: top;
border: 1px solid red;
}

.resources_rt {
height:100%;
width:50%;
display:inline-block;
white-space:normal;
vertical-align: top;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: `float: left` the image and apply `clearfix` to the container?

Comment: As far as I know you can't figure out the percentage of the text when mixing percentages and pixels, on the bright side you don't really have to give it any width at all if you float the image to the left with `float:left;`.

Comment: You could use CSS [`calc()`](http://caniuse.com/calc) if your browser support is acceptable.

Comment: How would I add in Float: left to my css?

Answer (score 0):

```
.resources_lt {
    height:100%;
    width:33%;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:normal;
    margin-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
}

.resources_lt img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.resources_rt {
    height:100%;
    max-width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:normal;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: right;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

You should add float: left; to the styles on your .resources_lt class, and float: right to .resources.rt.

Additionally, you need to style the images in .resources_lt so that they do not take up more than the space of their parent div (.resources_lt) and so that the height scales proportionate to the width. This will preserve the 20px spacing.

Finally, you need to add word-wrap:break-word to the text in .resources_rt -- at least for this example -- because longer words will poke out the side of the text area otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent over an hour for it .Hope it would be helpful for you.

```
    <head>
       <style>
    #wrapper-resources {
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        border: none;
        margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    }

     #resources_row {
        height:100%;
        white-space:nowrap;
        }

    .resources_cell1, .resources_cell2, .resources_cell3, .resources_cell4 {
        height:100%;
        width:24%;
        min-width: 80px;
        display:inline-block;
        white-space:normal;
        border: 1px solid #744646;
        opacity: 1;
        border-radius: 5px;
         box-shadow: 0 6px 16px #6A806A;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -ms-border-radius: 5px;
        -o-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition:all .2s ease-in-out ;
        -ms-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
        transition:all .2s ease-in-out ;


    }

    .resources_cell1:hover, .resources_cell2:hover, .resources_cell3:hover, .resources_cell4:hover {
       box-shadow: 0 0 5px #962828;
       opacity:0.75;
    }

    .resources_lt {
        height:100%;
        width:33%;
        display:inline-block;
        white-space:normal;
        margin-right: 20px;
        vertical-align: top;

    }

    .resources_rt {
        height:100%;
        width:50%;
        min-width: 80px;
        display:inline-block;
        white-space:normal;
        vertical-align: top;

    }

    .resources_rt p {
        font-family: cursive;
        font-style: normal;
        padding: 5px 0px 5px 10px;
        color: #000;
        line-height: 22px;
        opacity: 0.75;
        -webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition:all .2s ease-in-out ;
        -ms-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
        transition:all .2s ease-in-out ;
    }
    .resources_rt p:hover {
        color:#1FA719;
        font-style: normal;
        opacity: 1;

    }

    .resources_rt strong {
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        display: block;
    }
    .resources_lt img {

        margin:10%;
    }

    .resources_lt img:hover {
        opacity: 0.7;
    }

       </style>
    </head>

    <body>
          <div id="wrapper-resources">
            <div id="resources_row">
            <div class="resources_cell1">
                <div class="resources_lt">
                     <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/aha-soft/food/256/apple-icon.png" width="76" height="76" /> 
                </div>
                <div class="resources_rt">
                <p><strong>Webinar</strong>
                Capital Projects: Hidden Gems In The World</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="resources_cell2">
                <div class="resources_lt">
                 <img src="http://www.purelynaturalskin.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Sweet-Orange-Oil.jpg" width="76" height="76" /> 
                </div>
                <div class="resources_rt">
                <p><strong>Article</strong>
                 Capital Projects: Hidden Gems In The World</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="resources_cell3">
                <div class="resources_lt">
                 <img src="http://images.wikia.com/uncyclopedia/images/archive/d/d4/20080204233721!Pear.jpg" width="76" height="76" /> 
                </div>
                <div class="resources_rt">
                <p><strong>Blog</strong>
                 Capital Projects: Hidden Gems In The World</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="resources_cell4">
                <div class="resources_lt">
                 <img src="http://www.whataboutwatermelon.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/watermelon_simple.jpg" width="76" height="76" /> 
                </div>
                <div class="resources_rt">
                <p><strong>News</strong>
                 Capital Projects: Hidden Gems In The World</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
                </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]